# How to create a module that wraps other modules in android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

How to achieve this project structure? I mean, how to create a module that wraps other modules? Like core module in this case?

When I create a module it is automatically creating main and test packages which i don't need. And I cannot delete them.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a module set the name to :core:data, it should create a module :data, within another module :core (a grouping module)

then you can create new modules by just repeating the same and using diff names like `:core:theme` or `:core:etc`